# Generating 3D noise quickly in python

Tags: python, noise

I need a method to generate 3D simplex noise in python rather quickly. What methods are there out there to solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ pip install noise
```

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/noise/

> This package is designed to give you simple to use, fast functions for
>   generating Perlin noise in your Python programs. Perlin noise is famously
>   called the "salt" of procedural generation, as it adds considerable flavor in
>   its application. Noise is commonly used for imparting realism in textures,
>   animation and other procedural content generation -- placement of hairs,
>   heights of mountains, density of forests, waving of a flag, etc. etc.. ....
>
> The noise library includes native-code implementations of Perlin "improved"
>   noise and **Perlin simplex noise**.

Example code is included in the package, e.g. [`2dtexture`](http://code.google.com/p/caseman/source/browse/trunk/noise/examples/2dtexture.py?r=616):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use a mod function with a suitable period. there are quite a few pages around the www explaining mod functions.

just make sure it is also suitable for 3 dimensions, some mods that are suitable for 1 or 2 dimensions may not be suitable over 3.

Answer (score 0):

For more info.

http://snup.org/code-snippets/1153/python-n-dimensional-simplex-noise/

It has a simple code to generate simplex noise.

Comment: The link is dead now so this answer is useless now :-(